# Configuring the beast

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration

Can anybody guide me on WCF configuration, I was getting errors **(400) Bad Request** and trace viewer told me that:

*"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."*

I've looked to my client's app.config and changed properties accordingly, but the problem remained, then I've looked to server's web.config where I've found there is no `<service>...</service>` tag at all, so I've right-clicked `web.config` and selected `Edit WCF configuration` a window pop-upped several clicks and my wcf service configuration is ready BUT it started throwing

*"The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error"*

Trace viewer shows 3 warnings:

*"Failed to open System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost"*

*"Faulted System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost"*

*"ServiceHost faulted"*

Here are my server web.configs:

**Version 0 (working but with limitations):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\log\Traces1.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PopulizerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=VM-LU4\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Populizer;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**And the one that shows 3 warnings:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\log\Traces1.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PopulizerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=VM-LU4\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Populizer;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="NewServiceType">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1948/Commander.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="Populator.Commander">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:1948/Commander.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="CommanderEndpoint" contract="Private.ICommander" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

This is Version #3 of my web config still shows the same three warnings in TraceViewer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PopulizerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=VM-LU4\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Populizer;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpBasicBinding_Service01" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferSize="655360000"
          maxBufferPoolSize="655360000" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="655360000" maxStringContentLength="655360000"
            maxArrayLength="655360000" maxBytesPerRead="655360000" maxNameTableCharCount="655360000" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="NewServiceType">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1948/Commander.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="Populator.Commander">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:1948/Commander.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="httpBasicBinding_Service01" name="CommanderEndpoint" contract="Private.ICommander" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step configuration from working to non-working version of configuration helped out. Here's the server's web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PopulizerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=VM-LU4\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Populizer;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding  name="ICommander_BindingConfiguration"
                  closeTimeout="01:00:00"
                  openTimeout="00:01:00"
                  receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                  sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                  allowCookies="false"
                  bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                  maxBufferSize="1048576"
                  maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
                  messageEncoding="Text"
                  textEncoding="utf-8"
                  transferMode="Buffered"
                  useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        >
          <readerQuotas
              maxDepth="32"
              maxStringContentLength="1048576"
              maxArrayLength="1048576"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096"
              maxNameTableCharCount="1048576"
          />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding
          name="ICommunicator_BindingConfiguration"
          closeTimeout="01:00:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="1048576"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
          messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8"
          transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        >
          <readerQuotas
              maxDepth="32"
              maxStringContentLength="1048576"
              maxArrayLength="1048576"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096"
              maxNameTableCharCount="1048576"
          />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Populator.Commander">
        <endpoint contract="Private.ICommander" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ICommander_BindingConfiguration" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CommanderBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the max quote in binding element in **server** configuration? Check out an example below please.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISomeService" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: I've changed my web.config and added binding, but it still shows the same warnings and throws the same exception

Comment: Could you provide few more things: 1) is it publicly available? 2) Who is the host (iis or something else)? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a binding configuration.

Where you wrote:

```
bindingConfiguration = ""
```

you should write:

```
bindingConfiguration="httpBasicBinding_Service01"
```

and then configure:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpBasicBindingService 01" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      maxBufferSize="655360000"
      maxBufferPoolSize="655360000" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="655360000" maxStringContentLength="655360000"
        maxArrayLength="655360000" maxBytesPerRead="655360000" maxNameTableCharCount="655360000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: I've edited the web config the way you've mentioned but it still shows 3 warnings from version 2 of my config...